HDMI port not recognized
Unable to determine if unresponsive HDMI ports are a software/firmware issue or if it is a factory hardware issue. So my question is looking for the ideal troubleshooting procedure for unresponsive HDMI port(s).
Context:
New Asus Zenbook (UX5304M) re-imaged with Ubuntu 22.04, offline install then manual full apt/driver update (sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall). Verified bios install date/version is current (Version 202).
Condition:

Ubuntu display settings do not detect second display via HDMI
tail -f /var/log/{dmesg,syslog} - no logged events when plugging/unplugging known good HDMI monitors/cables.
USB-C dongle with USB-A connectors works fine but the HDMI port on that dongle doesn't log events either.
(All cables/monitors/dongle work fine with old Zenbook/Ubuntu.)

If it were a hardware issue I would expect the built-in HDMI port to fail, but the USB-C dongle HDMI port to work. But all HDMI connections fail (even through USB-C dongle, and even when all non-HDMI ports work on that dongle). So drivers or OS config?
(commands with HDMI connected)
sudo update-pciids && sudo lspci -v | grep VGA
(...)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P [Intel Graphics] (rev 08) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: VGA
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1c33
(...)

xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 2880 x 1800, current 2880 x 1800, maximum 2880 x 1800
default connected primary 2880x1800+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
   2880x1800     91.00* 

sudo lshw -short | grep display
/0/100/2                       display        Intel Corporation
/2             /dev/fb0        display        EFI VGA

uname -a
Linux sadtank 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.backlight=0"

